# How to disable specific Excel 2010 add-ins at startup?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to disable specific add-ins from loading in Excel 2010 every time I open up a new workbook or instance. How do I achieve this?

When I disable the specific add-ins by unchecking them in the normal Options menu, they still load when I open a new Excel.

Comment: application add-ins? when you uncheck, add-in should become inactive or disabled.

Comment: Yes, Excel Add-Ins. I uncheck them and they become inactive in the current Excel that I have open but if I close Excel and start a new one it comes back or even if I open up a new instance, they add-ins are back. I want them to be disabled across all new instances.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the Add-In?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the LoadBehavior value in the registry for a particular Excel add-in to change its load behavior.

To modify the load behavior so the add-in is disabled when Excel opens, find the following path in registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins

All of your addins should be listed there. Click on a particular addin to see the registry values. A REG_DWORD value present in all of them is LoadBehavior and you can set it to disable automatic loading by right-clicking the LoadBehavior key > Modify... and entering a value of 0.

Here is a Microsoft link describing the other load behaviors:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx#LoadBehavior

Comment: This looks very promising, if it works as expected I'll accept the answer. Thank you!

Comment: this answer also works in reverse (helped me re-enable a disabled addin)

Comment: There's a COM add in which is not present in the registry. Is there another registry somewhere with the other add ins?